# DHL configuration Europe problem

Tags: dhl

We are experiencing problem with DHL module for magento. When we set up the merchant address in Bulgaria we receive zero shipping charges for different shipping addresses in EU and international as well. When ew change the merchat address to a different country, for example Paris, France or Italy we get charges. Are shipping addresses from Bulgaria supported by DHL system or there is ? We have used the test service with or without entering the account number and setting up different configuration options. None worked.

This is the request: http://pastebin.com/0bNECcWZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys the problem was the Gateway URL to the xml request. I had test Gateway URL which returns zero values. When I changed it to the real Gateway URL everything is back to normal. the real URL is the default one - https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet